extreme-weather vs severe-weather tag?
I was writing a question on Earth Science SE and noticed that there are 2 similar tags, extreme-weather and severe-weather. The former has some usage guidance text while the latter doesn’t.
What is the difference between these two tags? If there is no difference, should they be merged?

They don't have to be the same, I think.  Extreme weather is far outside the norm, whereas severe weather is weather with a strong impact.  A thunderstorm is severe weather, but happens daily in some parts of the world, so it's not extreme.  Snowfall in Málaga, Spain would be extreme, but is not particularly severe.
